# Подключение файла PHP

Tags: php

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но долговременные поиски в интернете не помогли.
Я работаю в Open Server.
Пытаюсь подключить к файлу, находящемуся в папке pages файл auth.php, находящийся папкой выше. Перепробовал все, ничего не помогает, выдает ошибку

Warning: require(W:\domains\ncorp\pagesW:/domains/ncorp/auth.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\ncorp\pages\aboutus.php on line 3

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Честно, я в PHP нуль, но мне нужно быстро самому написать ограничение доступа для коллег, иначе некоторые данные можно будет легко получить простым переходом по ссылке

Comment: так может покажите, как именно пытаетесь подключить-то ?

Comment: прошу прощения, вот:
require __DIR__ . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/auth.php";

Comment: require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';

Comment: require __DIR__ . '../auth.php';

Comment: require __DIR__ . './auth.php';

Comment: либо `$_SERVER[...] . "/auth.php"` либо `../auth.php`. не надо тут DIR никаких.

Comment: а так `DIR.'\..\auth.php'`

Comment: @teran не факт, что в pages он попадает по прямой ссылке

Comment: @splash58 в тексте ошибки в вопросе как раз кажется и приведен вариант DIR + ROOT, и получает DIR = `w:\domains\ncorp\pages` конкатенированный с ROOT = `w:\domains\ncorp`

Comment: @teran ну да, поэтому и предлагаю вариант относительно DIR на папку выше. Казалось бы так - чтоб не думать, откуда он этот DIR берет :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно с текущей папки выйти и подключить файл который находится в папке рядом, то -

```
include_once '../pages/auth.php';   // можно без _once
```

или

```
require_once '../pages/auth.php';   // можно без _once
```

../ - говорит о том что выйти на уровень выше и дальше уже как пропишеш.